# Написать функцию, которая получает число из input , переводит его в число, и с помощью метода indexOf проверяет наличие в массиве

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно написать функцию, которая получает число из input `i-11`, переводит его в число, и с помощью метода `indexOf` проверяет наличие в массиве `d11`. Функция выводит в `out-11` -1 если такого числа нет в массиве, либо его индекс в массиве.
Помогите найти ошибку и прошу обяснить как єто работает уже пару часов сижу не могу врубиться

```
let d11 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

function f11() {
    let out = document.querySelector('.out-11');
    let a = document.querySelector('.i-11').value;
    a = a.parseInt();
    a = a.indexOf(d11.length);
    out.innerHTML = a;
}

document.querySelector('.b-11').onclick = f11;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
let d11 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

function f11() {
    let out = document.querySelector('.out-11');
    let inputValue = document.querySelector('.i-11').value;    
    indexOfinputValue = d11.indexOf(parseInt(inputValue));
    out.innerHTML = indexOfinputValue;
}

document.querySelector('.b-11').onclick = f11;
```

---

неправильно использовался метод `indexOf`. Перепутан местами объект, у которого должен был быть вызван метод и аргумент. И `parseInt` неправильно использовался

Answer (score 0):

Лучше вот так без всяких parseInt:

```
let d11 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

function f11() {
    let input = +document.querySelector('.i-11').value;
    let out = d11.indexOf(input);

    document.querySelector('.out-11').innerHTML = out;
}

document.querySelector('.b-11').onclick = f11;
```